# Add a fragment to the left side

Tags: android, view, fragment

When the user presses a button, I would like fragment B to appear on the left, like this:

[image]

Here is my code right now to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffff0000" />

<ViewGroup
    android:id="@+id/rightContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#ff00ffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.leftContainer, fragmentA);
ft.add(R.id.rightContainer, fragmentB);
ft.commit();
```

Unfortunately, all this gives me is a black screen.  I do not even see the background colors for the fragments.

Comment: Have you tried having two layouts and using `setContentView()`?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but I will try it if I cannot come up with a more "elegant" solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to:

```
add B
add A
call ft.hide(B);
```

Then when needed:

```
call ft.show(B);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you start out the layout with both B and A added, but set B's visibility to "GONE"?  Then, when you want B to appear, change its visibility.

If I were doing this, I would put them both in a LinearLayout. I would set B's width to 0dp and its layout_weight to 1.  I would set A's width to 0dp and its layout_weight to 2.  When B is gone, A will fill the entire Layout, and when B appears, you'd get a layout that's 1/3 B and 2/3 A.

ETA: here's some code:

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLevel"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    >
  <TextView  
      android:id="@+id/B"
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:text="B"
      android:background="#f00"
      android:textSize="36sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:visibility="gone"
      />
  <TextView  
      android:id="@+id/A"
      android:layout_width="0dp" 
      android:layout_weight="2" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:text="A"
      android:background="#00f"
      android:textSize="36sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

FooApp.java:

```
package org.efalk.fooapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FooApp extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView A, B;
    boolean gone = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        A = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.A);
        B = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.B);
        A.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        gone = !gone;
        B.setVisibility(gone ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  When B goes away, A does not resize to fill the screen.  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that when the fragments are laid out, their LinearLayout.LayoutParams are switched to FrameLayout.LayoutParams, which no longer carry a weight.

Comment: I'm attaching some source code that I believe does what you want.  Touch the "A" widget to make the "B" widget come and go.

Comment: Hmmm.  You wrote "fragment" and I read "widget".  Sorry about that. I don't know if my answer will do you any good.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would work, but unfortunately fragments are sort of weird.  Setting the visibility to gone does not notify the other fragment(s) to resize.  You have to call FragmentTransaction.hide(B)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layout, either in xml or otherwise to serve as containers for those fragments. Then simply add the fragment A in the fragmenttransaction. Then you'll have some viewgroup in your layout that you can add Fragment A to and you'll need to specify which view group you'd like to add the fragment to in your transaction. also, you need be sure to call commit on the transaction for your changes to take effect. If you're looking to do some nice transitions, etc then you'll need to think a little more about how to structure your layouts and the logic of adding the fragment in, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I edited the OP but now I do not see content from either fragment (just black screen).  Is this more like what you were suggesting?